# Node, Express, React and DB structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, directory-structure

I want to create a multipage website with multiple users. I am new to react, so I am not quite sure how the folder structure should look like. On the backend I will use either a mySQL or noSQL db.

I have read some articles, but there seems to be many different thoughts on how the structure should look like. My thoughts so far is that it should look something like this:

- models

  - user-db-query.js
  - etc.
- public

  - css
  - fonts
  - js
  - External Libraries

    - bootstrap, jquery etc.
- routes

  - about
  - admin
  - etc.
- middlewares

  - passport.js
  - db-connection.js
  - etc.
- views

  - layouts
  - partials

    - navbar-logged-in
    - navbar-not-logged-in
    - etc
  - index
  - about

I believe this is a bad structure from what I can see from e.g. this repo: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit which should be a reliable source with 3800 forks.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

For personal projects/repositories, while it is good to follow conventions and the link you gave is certainly a good example, it's really down to what you are most comfortable with. There's no "bad" structure as long as it makes sense to you.

If the project is or will be shared, then I do recommend trying to follow convention as closely as possible. Not only are other people more likely to know what's happening and where, it can also make it easier to debug and find other solutions online since other people will have similar folder structures.